# is it ok to copy a git folder in windows to manage multiple branches?

Tags: windows, git, gitkraken

I'm new to git and have a git repository that I use with GitKraken.
In this repository I have multiple branches, and can move from branch to branch in order make modifications where necessary.

I am now in a situation where I'll be making some large modifications to 1 branch that I do not want to commit but in the meantime I would like to make some minor modifications to another branch.

I'm used to work with TFS and there I can just checkout branch to another folder.

I've tried to just copy the folder and my first impression is that this should work....

But, I have seen online remarks that say that I should clone a repository instead.

The git version is lower then 2.5 so I can't use Git-worktree.

Is it ok to just copy the folder or can this have an unexpected effect?

Comment: "that I do not want to commit" - you can always commit them locally then come back later and undo the commit to get your files back and leave state exactly how you'd want it.

Comment: This is essentially what [feature branches are for](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). FYI there is no problem with copying your GIT repo to another folder. But it will be an exact copy (remotes an all), so what's the point? It sounds like you want a feature branch, but don't push it, as suggested by @Rup

Comment: Remember a GIT repo is an exact copy of the **entire repository**. So everything that's on the server you have too. So you can do whatever you want on your local copy

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you copy the whole folder from the root of the checkout, including the hidden `.git` folder, then you can make changes to each working copy independently. Each contains their own copy of the repository objects and they will behave exactly as if you have run two separate clones.

As discussed in the comments this isn't necessarily a good use case for this, though: it would be easier (and more disk-space-efficient) to commit your large changes to a local branch so that you can then switch and make other changes. There's no real downside to this; if you do want to remove that temporary commit later then that's easily done as well.

However if you are going to do this, then you probably want to

- run a `git repack -ad` first, so that there are fewer files in the objects tree to copy
- consider using `git clone --reference` instead, which might be slightly more disk-space-efficient
- or you want a clean working copy you can create a new working copy folder, copy only the hidden `.git` folder into the new working copy and then `git reset --hard` to check out all of the files there too.

Comment: Will they act as *separate* clones?  Or will they be something inextricably entangled?  For example, if you commit in one, and push to origin, will the other clone then fail to download the new revision during sync, since the revision metadata says it originated from that clone GUID?

Comment: AFAIK there's no such thing as a clone GUID, and the server doesn't track clones, but happy to be corrected. I've tried cloning the same repo twice and diffing the state: there are timestamp differences in .git/logs, but the .git/index file is also different and it's a binary format so I can't easily tell what's changed. I'd have guessed any GUID would live in .git/config, but it's possible it's in index I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see if git stashing will work for you.  I don't recommend copying to a new folder.  Mostly because I don't know if it's even possible and I've never seen that as a recommendation.  Cloning should also work but it sounds like you are interested in shelving/stashing vs. committing your changes in branch1 before checking out branch2.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: I think it works best if you have changes you "don't want to commit" but would like to save before checking out a different branch.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking about. They want to be able to make multiple commits locally. Pleas re-read the question. *I am now in a situation where I'll be making some large modifications to 1 branch that I do not want to commit*

Comment: I read it. "Is it OK to copy a git folder"  You're saying the OP wants to make multiple commits.  Are you sure you read the question?  There's also no mention of a remote.  What if all of the work is local and there is no remote branch.

Comment: If your answer if "I don't know if it's even possible" (direct quote from this answer), that's a strong hint that you have a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Agreed, it should have been a comment.